# C#: How can I use a string to specify the Type (T) for a generic method?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have some ugly code that looks something like this:

```
    switch (f.TypeName)
    {
        case "TypeOne":
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyMethod<TypeOne>), args);
            break;
        case "TypeTwo":
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyMethod<TypeTwo>), args);
            break;

        ...

        case "TypeTwenty":
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyMethod<TypeTwenty>), args);
            break;
    }
```

I would really like to get rid of the switch statement and do something along these lines:

```
    var myTypeDescriptor = Type.GetType(f.TypeName); //<== clearly not this, but similar
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyMethod<myTypeDescriptor>), args);
```

where MyMethod looks like this:

```
    protected void MyMethod<T>(object args)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I've poked around some and have found a number of examples where the generic is a generic class, but no examples where it is a generic method.  And definitely not any examples where it is being passed to a delegate.

While this appears, at first glance, to be a duplicate of [How do I use reflection to call a generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method), I am not simply trying to call the method.  It is being passed to the WaitCallback delegate.  Perhaps this is a two part question:  1) how do I retrieve the generic method via reflection and 2) having obtained a handle to the method, how do I pass it as an argument to the WaitCallback delegate?

Anyone have any ideas?  Is this even possible?

Comment: How are you using the generic parameter in `MyMethod`? Can you create a version which takes an explicit `Type` parameter?

Comment: can you show implementation of `MyMethod<T>`? you oversimplified. if `T` is not used anywhere in input or output, then It feels like design problem and you are probably solving wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is brief idea

```
var type = Type.GetType(f.TypeName);
var methodInfo = typeof(MethodHoderType).GetMethod("MyMethod");
var constructedMethodInfo = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(type);
constructedMethodInfo.Invoke(...);
```

If it is instance method you should create an instance of type `type` to pass to `Invoke` method or pass `null` as first parameter if it is `static method`.

Look at the [Type.GetType Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod Method (Type[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

If you can create instances of the types from the strings you have (if you know them fully qualified), you can use `MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(Type[] typeArguments)`

Take a look at [the docs in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Helps. Instead of a string Just build a decorator to take in the Type that Queues the Item.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var arguments = new object();

        Execute<ObjectA>(args);
        Execute<ObjectB>(args);
        Execute<ObjectC>(args);
        Execute<ObjectA>(args);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void Execute<T>(object args) where T:BaseObject
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyMethod<T>), args);
    }

    static void MyMethod<T>(object args) where T:BaseObject
    {
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(T).FullName);
    }
}

public class BaseObject
{
}

public class ObjectA : BaseObject
{
}

public class ObjectB : BaseObject
{
}

public class ObjectC : BaseObject
{
}
```

[image]